# PSD to HTML/CSS ON PHP/MYSQL SCRIPT

Tags: css, html

I have an auction script that uses PHP/MYSQL. I'm not satisfied with the look and feel but like the the overall function. I was planning on having a graphic designer come up with PSD files to give the site a new look. I'm guessing I need a variety of pages made up. Is it easy to integration the PSD into the existing script, keep the functionality but change the look?

Would you be able to get this done for the whole site within a budget of $1000. Is freelance a good place to look?

Does this mess with the PHP/MYSQL code and cause problems?

Also is it hard to make it optimized for other devices such as tablets and Phones and not just pc's (PC's being main market). And will this extra graphics cause the site to run slower because of extra load time?

Thanks to anyone that can help me answer these questions.

Comment: Janus provides a good answer. I'd also add that while it's not 'hard' to optimize for other devices, it will take work, and a PSD won't magically make that happen. You need to hire someone that understands responsive web design--both to design the visuals, and implement the responsive markup.

Answer (score 5):

I think you’re misunderstanding what PSD means.

PSD files are Photoshop files. They can be opened in Photoshop, and not much else. You cannot integrate them directly into web pages, since browsers cannot open them.

Normally, you would use Photoshop to create/edit images that you then export as JPG/PNG files that browsers know what to do with. These images are then used as graphical elements in the website design.

The website’s structure (HTML) and layout (CSS) are quite separate from your images. A graphic designer will normally only make mockup pictures of how the site can/should look and provide you with the image files needed; actually implementing the HTML/CSS is up to you. Alternatively, you can hire someone who does both graphic design and web design (who will more commonly call themselves web designers than graphic designers).

Integrating your own PHP code into the finished HTML structure, though, would be your job, unless you want to give the web designer access to your server and your scripts (which I would not recommend). PHP and MySQL both run on the server and are not visible to the user, while HTML, CSS, and images (which the graphic/web designer deals with) originate on the server, but are run in the user’s browser. The two sides generally do not influence or trip up each other, as long as your PHP code with your MySQL queries are included in the correct places.

Whether this is doable withing a budget of $1,000 depends entirely on where you are, how big your site is, what type of design you’re looking for, etc.; we cannot answer that here.